# Refresh only the custom header views in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My `UITableView` has custom `UIView` headers in every section. I am needing to refresh only the headers and not the other content in the section. I have tried out `[self.tableView headerViewForSection:i]` and it does not return anything even though it should. Is there anyway that I can do this?

Edit: Code based around new suggestion

I have given this a shot as well and it calls/updates the UIView within that method, but the changes do not visually propagate onto the screen.

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.objects.count; i++) {
    UIView *headerView = [self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:i];
    [headerView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Are you using a nib to load your headers, or are you creating them programmatically in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`?

Comment: I am creating them programmatically in the stated method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of calling `setNeedsDisplay`, configure the header yourself by setting it's properties. And of course you have to get the actual headers in the table, don't call the delegate method, because that method usually creates a new header view.

I usually do this in a little helper method that is called from `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` as well.

e.g.:

```
- (void)configureHeader:(UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)header forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // configure your header
    header.textLabel.text = ...
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"Header"];
    [self configureHeader:header forSection:section];
}

- (void)reloadHeaders {
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]; i++) {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:i];
        [self configureHeader:header forSection:i];
    }
}
```

Comment: All of this works great, but the call for `UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:i];` does not return anything. I tried doing `[self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:i]` and it returns a header and takes me to configure, but still doesn't display the changes visually on screen.

Comment: if `[self.tableView headerViewForSection:i]` returns nil, then your tableView does not have a header for this section, or it is currently not visible. And of course `[self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:i]` will return a view, but this view is newly created and is not part of the view hierarchy; you can't see that view.

Comment: What can I do to check this? Visually the table view has headers for each section and they are being instantiated exactly the way you wrote above.

Comment: I just figured it out. I had setup my custom class to return a UIView instead of UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Once I did that everything worked great! Would you recommend to return a UITableViewHeaderFooterView every time in a viewForHeader/Footer method?

Comment: when my tableview reload or when i scroll tableview, tableview header called. where i did my image animation. but i want to do animation on click of navigation bar button. and not for every time user come on this screen.
       I try above code but viewforHeaderInSection gives me nil and  above code not return view.

Answer (score 3):

Create your own subclass of UIView for the headerView, and add a couple of methods to it so your view controller can send whatever UI updates you want to it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` only serves to trigger the `drawRect:` method of the receiving view. Unless this is where your text color logic is (that is, in the drawRect method of your UIView subclass that you are using for header views), nothing is likely to change. What you need to do is directly call something on the header views to update their state based on your new or changed data or directly access the label in the header view and change it yourself while iterating through them. `setNeedsDisplay` will only trigger code found in the `drawRect:` method of the view.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this exact problem and only overcame it by keeping a pointer to the headers as they were created.  I did it in Swift and with a swift only dictionary type but the idea could be massaged into objC somehow.

```
  var headers : [ Int : UIView ] = [ : ] //dictionary for keeping pointer to headers

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        if let h = super.tableView(tableView , viewForHeaderInSection: section) { //or create your view (this viewController inherits it)..
        self.headers.updateValue(h , forKey: section) //keep a pointer to it before you return it..
        return h
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your custom header views, use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instead of a simple `UIView` and when you initialize it, use something like this:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView *cell = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"];
```

The `reuseIdentifier` will tell your `UITableView` to keep track of the header and it should no longer return `null` when you try to access it with `[self.tableView headerViewForSection:i]`

You should then be able to use `setNeedsDisplay` on the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` you get back from `headerViewForSection` after making your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** Solution:

Delegate method of your table view:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // Ideally, dequeue your header view...
    var view: UITableViewHeaderFooterView?
    if section == 0 { view = ... // dequeue appropriately
    } else if section == 1 { view = ... // dequeue appropriately
    } else ... // etc.

    setupHeaderView(&view)
    return view
}
```

In the area of code where you want to do the header view update:

```swift
var headerView = tableView.headerView(forSection: i)
setupHeaderView(&headerView)
```

Header setup method:

```swift
func setupHeaderView(_ view: inout UITableViewHeaderFooterView?) {
    // do something with `view` here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.reloadSections([0,0], with: .automatic)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614954-reloadsections

Comment: This reloads the whole first section (header and cells) - which is not what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

> Swift 5 :

If you are using custom view as a table header view then try below code

-- Make your custom class as a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

```
class MyCustomHeaderView : UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var sampleLabel: UILabel!
 }
```

-- Then fetch your view using below method (using section number)

```
func updateHeaderView() {
// This is for section no. 1, you can use `for loop` for all sections

 if let headerView = self.myTableView.headerView(forSection: 1) as? MyCustomHeaderView { 
   // Set values or update constraints to your view 
   headerView.sampleLabel.text = "your new text goes here"
   headerView.sizeToFit() //Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews 
   self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
   self.myTableView.endUpdates() 
   // if you are using for loop then keep this `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` outside loop
    }
 }
```