# Dynamically change the section header text on a static cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController, with its table view having static cells, defined in a storyboard.

My table view has two sections. The first with two cells, and the second section has three cells. The second section also has text in its header.

What I would like to do is that when the user taps the first or second cells in the first section, to update the header text of the second section. Do so dynamically and with dynamic content (say the date and time is displayed there as of the moment they tap cells).

I have tried numerous things, but the `viewForHeaderSection` is only called once.

I registered the header section cell with

```
tableView.registerClass(TableSectionHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "secondSectionCell")
```

Where `TableSectionHeader` is simply:

```
class TableSectionHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView { }
```

I am then able to dynamically set the section header, like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 1 {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("secondSectionCell") {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "hello world"
            return cell
        }

    }

    return nil
}
```

I also have implemented the following override, since some people suggest that when implementing `viewForHeaderInSection`, it is also required:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40.0
}
```

Even still. `viewForHeaderInSection` is only called once.

Am I able to somehow refresh the section header text dynamically as described above?

Comment: You can not do it. There is no official documentation for this. You need to do custom methods, like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501952/refresh-only-the-custom-header-views-in-a-uitableview , however, I would strongly suggest you leave the section headers alone, and use cells in their place instead as the first cell in each section. Unless you want to do some sticky headers or other stuff that you really need.

Comment: @Sneak I like your suggestion. Probably the easiest way to go. The only thing is fiddling around with the table view to deal with the lines that separate cells, and how they are inset from the left edge of the tableview.

Comment: tableView.reloadSections will reload the header (and footer) as well as the content for that section

Comment: @dbarros it's really not that much of fiddling , actually much easier and customizable. just add register a XIB , subclass the Cell, and use Autolayout, you can customize everything 100% . If you want spacing, you can simply add borders in the XIB with Autolayout etc. customize bordercolors, everything you need. :)

Comment: @Dale I think the OP only wants to update the sectionHeader and nothing else. As far as I understand though.

Comment: @Sneak that's correct, just wanted to update the header text, since that's all that could change.

Comment: @Sneak sure, but when I was faced with the same problem I decided the overheads of reloading the rows in the section were small enough price to pay for updating (in my case) the footer. There is no visible consequence to the user just a bit of extra processing. Worked for me :)

Comment: @Dale Well, that isn't correct, if you reload the cells, your cellForRow will get called together with the rest of your datasource and delegates. If you have a UITextField in the cell for example, and the user have a current input, the input will be nilled out. If you have a movie/video playing, it will reload. If you have an image set from an NSURL, it will reload... and so on etc. :) it's all from case-to-case , if it works for your case your answer is 100% valid, however, I think the OP have some content that he dont want to reload. therefore he only wants to reload the specific section.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually achieve this using traditional table view way easily.

Even though it is static UITableView, in your dataSource view controller, you can still implement `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

So how do you update the title on the fly? Create a property for this view controller, say `NSString *titleForSecondSection`. Whenever user tap the cells in the first section, you just need to update this property in the callback `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

The last step is to call `[self.tableView reload]` after you modified the `titleForSecondSection` property. Or if you don't want to reload the whole table view, just call `- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`

To be clear, in your `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`, for sections that don't need to change title, just return a static string. For sections that need to change title, return the dynamic property you created.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just noticed you are using Swift. Should've post in Swift. But it's the same idea. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

viewForHeaderInSection would only be called when the tableview is reloaded. So assuming you don't want to reload the whole tableview, you might need to change the content of label directly.
pseudo codes like:

```
var label_first_section_header //as global variable
```

then in viewForHeaderInSection just point it to the label

```
if section == 1 {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("secondSectionCell") {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "hello world"
        label_first_section_header = cell.textLabel
        return cell
    }
}
```

then you can change the text dynamically whenever you want, for example in didSelectRowAtIndexPath