# Swift - Reload UITableView Header

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm try to reload only UITableView section header **without reloading whole section or reload whole table**. Thanks in advance.

note :- I follow answers of already answered question. But I still cannot figure out this.

Comment: you can check this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/71378148/7301439

Answer (score 3):

Use this method to reload section. Add index set of section which you want to reload.

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(0..<1), with: .automatic)
```

Comment: I just want to reload header of section.

Comment: Then call reloadSections(IndexSet(0..<1), with: .automatic). it will call method tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? in this method change the title.

Comment: the title is not being updated using this method unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard method to do that, you can use `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` function to get the section header from UITableView and do the updates.

Answer (score -1):

Add-on to [user3608500](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3608500/user3608500) answer

**Reload Header view only**

I think your header view class is extending UITableViewHeaderFooterView class. Add a function in the extension

```
extension UITableViewHeaderFooterView{
     func reloadHeaderCell(){
        preconditionFailure("This method must be overridden")
    }
}
```

Now override this in your Header class as below

```
class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
   override func reloadHeaderCell() {
      ////// add your logic to reload view
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call below line to refresh views

```
self.tableView?.headerView(forSection:0)?.reloadHeaderCell()
```

**Reload entire Section view**

For reloading entire section/sections view including rows(here section 0 and 2), you can call like below

```
  self.tableView?.reloadSections([0,2], with: .none)
```

**Reload entire table view**

For reloading entire table view, you can call like below

```
self.tableView?.reloadData()
```

**Reload particular row**

For reloading particular row/rows, you can call like below

```
self.tableView?.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 1, section: 2), IndexPath(item: 4, section: 3)], with: .none)
```

Above code will reload 1st item in 2nd section and 4th item in 3rd section.

Answer (score -2):

How i handled in for my app was

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   tableview.tableHeaderView = customHeader
}
```

then to reload data simply call the method:

```
self.view.layoutSubviews()
```