# Dynamically update an ImageView in a tableview section

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a table view with 2 (or more) sections. I have added an ImageView into it and need to change the image view according the values which are containing in an array at the beginning and when selecting/deselecting a cell. I created the view as follows,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let viewHeader = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 40))
    buttonCheck = UIButton(type: .custom)
    buttonCheck!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    buttonCheck!.tag = section
    buttonCheck!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapSection(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    viewHeader.addSubview(buttonCheck!)
}
```

This adds the ImageView fine and when I load the table data initially, I need to set the image view programatically. To change the image view I did,

```
if tableViewData.contains(where: self.tags.contains) {
   buttonCheck!.setImage(UIImage(named: "CheckmarkCircle"), for: .normal)
} else {
   buttonCheck!.setImage(UIImage(named: "DeselectedCheckmarkCircle"), for: .normal)
}
```

I called this inside `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` method. The problem here is, When I select a cell from section one(section = 0), it affects to the second section(section = 1) header image view. In other work when I select a cell from section one the second section's header image is changing. How may I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are overriding the `buttonCheck` every time `viewForHeaderInSection` is called, meaning it will always hold a reference to the last button you created.

It would be better if you created a dictionary to hold the imageviews (where the index is the section), like this on the controller scope:

```
var imageViews: [Int: UIButton] = [:]
```

Then change `viewForHeaderInSection` to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let viewHeader = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 40))
    let buttonCheck = UIButton(type: .custom)
    buttonCheck!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    buttonCheck!.tag = section
    buttonCheck!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapSection(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    imageViews[section] = buttonCheck
    viewHeader.addSubview(buttonCheck!)
}
```

Then on the `didSelect` and `didDeselect` update the imageView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    imageViews[indexPath.section]?.setImage(UIImage(named: "CheckmarkCircle"), for: .normal)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    imageViews[indexPath.section]?.setImage(UIImage(named: "DeselectedCheckmarkCircle"), for: .normal)
}
```

Please take into account that performance wise, this might not be the best solution. It would be better create a custom view extending [UITableViewHeaderFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview) and take into account view reusablity.

Comment: Just for my curiosity: are headers non-reusable? This approach would only work correctly if all headers would only be created once and never reused.

Comment: @lennartk headers can also be reused. Yes. I believe that if the views were reused, the dictionary would have different sections pointing to the same view.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple approaches you can take. The quick and dirty way is to just call `tableView.reloadData()`, which will force every element in your TableView to be reloaded with the current data from your DataSource.

If you want to take a more performant approach, you could choose to only reload the section headers by looping over them. This is very well answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501952/refresh-only-the-custom-header-views-in-a-uitableview) question. Good luck.